# Access Form don't create new entry because a one-to-one relation is not complete

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-forms

In my database I have a `tblCrewInformatio` related one-to-one to a `tblCouserExpireDate` (Auto filled from another source and no edition available).
Not all Crew have Course information (because they are new at the company)

In my Form I get `tblCrewInformation` and associate with the process of Flag Registration Requirements (A check list of documents we must attend to submit the registration) In this form I have a field blocked that show the expiration date of the courser, this way before I check the document as "ok" I see if it still valid.

[image]

Access doesn't let me Create a Flag Registration for a Crew Member that doesn't has a `tblCouserExpireDate` data.

I tried to uncheck "enforce referential integrity" or change the join type, but it didn't change the status.

Comment: Don't set Matricula as PK in tblCouserExpireDate. It is a foreign key. I would probably just have 1 table and tolerate empty fields. Are those UltimoEbarque and Validade fields yes/no type? Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables.

Comment: UltimoEmbarque and Validade fields are Date type. I will try to join the tables. Probably it will be easier.